# How to get serial flow control of multiple asynchronous http requests and their callbacks in node.js?

Tags: json, http, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have tried this many ways (queue, with/without async module, handler, etc.), but I cannot figure out how to apply serial flow control to an asynchronous http request and its callback. I have an array of urls I want to use to make http requests with and insert individual documents within each response into a mongo db collection. Once the inserts are finished I want to proceed to the next http request. Here is where I am at, but this still kicks off all the http requests before the inserts happen.

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var urls = ['http://getsomejson/1', 'http://getsomejson/2', 'http://getsomejson/3'];

async.forEachSeries(urls, function(url, callback) {
    // All of these requests are firing before http request callback logic is executed
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        async.forEachSeries(body.docs, function(doc, callback) {
            // Do the inserts for this response
            callback();
        }, function(err) {
            // handle errors
        });
    })
    callback();
}, function(err) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When are you calling the 'callback' functions?

Comment: In this example I am using the request module to make requests so the callback I am referring to is the function (error, response, body) {} I need to be able to control what is inside of here after each request, but I can not figure out how to that before all the requests are fired off.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code sample to show the calls to the callbacks that you are referring to. I have those in my application so that was not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback` passed to the `function(url, callback)` function is what triggers the next element in the series. If you just call it at the end like that, it is doing a loop just like if you did a `for` loop. You should call that callback in the completion function of the request. That way it will jump to the next item after the request is done.

```
async.forEachSeries(urls, function(url, callback) {
  // All of these requests are firing before http request callback logic is executed
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {

    async.forEachSeries(body.docs, function(doc, callback) {
      // Do the inserts for this response
      callback();
    }, function(err) {
      // handle errors

      callback();
    });
  })
}, function(err) {
  // handle errors
});
```